# Profile page of logged in user always visible even when editing the URL to go to another users page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am constructing a social networking site. I have created `profile_page.php` which displays the profile of the current user and will eventually, also show the profile pages of other users on the website.

At the moment, if I am logged in, and click on the button `Profile` it will direct me to my profile page (`http://localhost/profile_page/freddy`), however, when I edit the URL to, for example: `http://localhost/profile_page/tim`, who is a registered user, it will display the page for user `freddy`.

I know the page is on `Tim's` profile page, because I have certain buttons which only appear to other users, and I also know it is on `Tim's` page because of the URL `http://localhost/profile_page/tim`, but I am unsure to why it is always displays the content (such as profile picture as well as posts) of user `freddy`.

At the moment, I have the following piece of code which determines whose profile the browser is on:

```
<?php
$user = "";
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $user = ($_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($user)) { //check if the user exists
        $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($check) === 1) {
            $get        = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
            $user       = $get['username'];
            $fname      = $get['first_name'];
        } else { // refresh page 
            // if the user doesnt exist i.e. ?u=fakeUser - it will redirect them to the index page.
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/index.php\">";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Edit**:

Rewrite Rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ profile_page.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^profile(?:_page)?/([\w-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `http://localhost/profile_page?u=freddy` or `...?u=tim`? You are checking the $_GET['u'] variable (which is appended to the end of a URL) for the username, not the last part of the URL itself.

Comment: @mark.hch Sorry, I forgot to mention, I have written some Rewrite Rules which should allow me to directly type the users name at the end to get to their page. I will edit my question to show you these rules.